# Swift PrepareForSegue ERROR Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe

Tags: multithreading, swift

I have really big problems when i try to compile my PrepareForSegue function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "findMap" {
        let MapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let destinationTitle = filteredDepartments[indexPath.row].name
            MapViewController.title = destinationTitle
        } else {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let destinationTitle = departments[indexPath.row].name
            MapViewController.title = destinationTitle
        }
    }
}
```

The error opens in the Thread section in the "trap"-row:

-->  0x2f6e18:  trap

and the error code is as above:

--> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe

I think the error is in this line:

```
if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
```

Bur i don't know how to solve it , so please help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your code is supposed to mean, but my guess is that you mean this:

```
if sender === self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
```

Notice the use of the triple-equals operator to mean "is the same object as".

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_object_identity